# Calendar.getTime().getYear() gives back 0113 instead of 2013

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm making a little game. When the game is starting for the first time i saves the time since 01.01.1970 in seconds in the SharedPreferences.

Now i want to give this date out on my screen in this form: DD.MM.YYYYY

I used the Calendar function but it give back 02.04.0113 so, there are missing 1900 Years.

Here is my Code:

```
private void initBornTXT() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("LIFE", 0);
    long born = pref.getLong("BIRTHDAY", 0);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    c.setTimeInMillis(0);

    c.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int)born);
    int year = c.getTime().getYear();
    int month = c.getTime().getMonth();
    int day = c.getTime().getDay();
    String string_born = String.format("%02d.%02d.%04d", day, month, year);
    TextView born_txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBorn);
    born_txt.setText(string_born);
}
```

What coud be wrong?

Comment: use c.setTimeInMillis(1000 * born)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing's wrong. You've just not looked at the documentation for the method you're calling, [`Date.getYear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29):

> Returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

Note that you should have received a warning that you're using a deprecated API: don't just ignore those warnings.

Also, do yourself a favour and don't do the formatting yourself: use `SimpleDateFormat` instead. (Or ideally, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead...) That way you can avoid the *month* being wrong, too... you may not have noticed that you're a month off due to months being 0-based, which is common to both `Calendar` and `Date`.

Comment: I am wondering what was the idea for creation this method that will subtract 1900 years ?

Comment: @Stanislav: I suspect it's due to the `struct tm` in C/C++: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

Comment: @besnep: You're using `String.format` having obtained the values separately yourself. Don't do that: just use `SimpleDateFormat` which already *knows* about calendars (and time zones, and locale-specific separators) etc.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : I must admit that i don't understand the SimpleDataFormat.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

But there are so many lines for such a easy thing... i don't get where the benefit is?
I came from programming C and used the sprintf(string, "bla %i bla",int). The String.format seems to be the right thing for me.

Comment: @besnep: It's really, really not. You just create an appropriate `SimpleDateFormat` object (setting the time zone and locale if you want) then call `format` on it, passing in a `Date`. I can assure you it'll be a lot less code then you've currently got... and it won't have those bugs!

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I added these two lines:

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String string_death = formatter.format(calendar_death);

But it crashes...

Comment: @besnep: "It crashes" is never enough information - but I suspect it's because you're passing in a `Calendar` rather than a `Date`. Try passing in `calendar_death.getTime()` - although as I say, Joda Time is a much nicer API.

Comment: @oh year thx. You where right, the SimpleDateFormat made my code 2 lines shorter and bug free. :) 
I also want to get the Time in between to calendars in days.
Here i also read in other help threads to juse the Joda API.
But do i have to install something anywhere? Android? Phone? 
I am mostly new to Android programming so, don't know what i have to do with a api^^

Comment: @besnep: Well, I'd personally recommend learning Java *separately* from learning Android - learn it with console applications, learn how to use the 3rd party APIs, etc. But everyone has different styles.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I was starting like that but it is more a question of time... In shool we have to make a big programming project.
We learned C and C++ but i wanted to make a little game for android.
I was more like "if you are able to programm with one language than you can do the most other languages too." and that worked for now.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal, documented behavior. See JavaDoc for [Date#getYear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29).

A better way to get the year would be:

`c.get(Calendar.YEAR)`

Comment: Oh... i didn't know that. Confusing that everything is working with 1970 except the calendar^^

Answer (score 1):

You're using getTime, which returns a date object.  Dates are based on 0=1900.  So this is the expected output.  Use a SimpleDateFormat instead.

Kudos for creating a Y2K bug though :)